# Python socket sends the first message but nothing afterward

Tags: python, sockets, general-network-error

My socket sends the first message but nothing afterward.
The output in the server:

`What do you want to send?`

`lol`

The client receives:

`From localhost got message:`

`lol`

And then it doesn't want to send anything else. 
I don't get the `what do you want to send` printed anymore.

My code:

`server.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()
print ("got host name:", host)

port = 9996
print("connecting on port:", port)

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))
print("binding host and port")

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)
print("Waiting for connection")

while True:
    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
    msg = input("what do you want to send?\n")
    clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
```

`client.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket # create a socket object

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # get local machine

# name
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9996 # connection to hostname on the port.

s.connect((host, port)) # Receive no more than 1024 bytes

while True:
    msg = s.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode("ascii"))
```

Comment: The client only connects once (OK) but the server waits for an incoming connection every start of the `while` loop.

Comment: OH! im so dumb! thanks alot! i finally got this working for the first time.

Comment: @timgeb Please turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: @GottaAimHigherPal is there still something unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The client only connects once (OK) but the server waits for an incoming connection every start of the `while` loop.

Since there are no more connection requests by a client, the server will freeze on the second iteration.

If you just want to handle a single client, move `clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()` before the `while` loop. If you want to handle multiple clients, the standard way is to have the server accept connections inside the `while` loop and [spawn a thread for each client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828264/how-to-make-a-simple-multithreaded-socket-server-in-python-that-remembers-client).

You can also use [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), but that may be a bit overkill if you are just starting out.