# Python closing socket and connection in a threaded server?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

We have a Python socket threaded server example. It is a slightly modified version from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23828265/2008247. The example works and my tests confirm that it performs better than the blocking server.

But in the example, the socket and the connection objects are not closed. Both objects have `close()` method. (The close method on a connection is called only on Exception. I would expect it to be called for each connection when it ends.) Do we not need to somehow call them? If so, how?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import threading

class ThreadedServer():

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):

        self.sock.listen(5)

        while True:

            con, address = self.sock.accept()
            con.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target=self.listenToClient,
                             args=(con, address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, con, address):

        while True:
            try:
                data = con.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    # Set the response to echo back the recieved data
                    response = data
                    con.send(response)
                else:
                    raise Exception('Client disconnected')
            except:
                con.close()
                return False


def main():

    ThreadedServer('', 8001).listen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [[Python.Docs]: socket.close()](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close):

> Sockets are automatically closed when they are garbage-collected, but it is recommended to [close()](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.close) them explicitly, or to use a [with](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement around them.

So, all the sockets will be closed eventually. However, if server runs for a long time and it (quickly) creates / destroys a lots of connections, you might end up in the situation of running out of file descriptors, and as a consequence new sockets couldn't be created, therefore it's good to have them manually closed.

There are 2 cases.

#### 1. Close the server socket

Things are simple. Add a "destructor", or better: finalizer ([[Python.Docs]: Data model - object.__del__(self)](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)) to your *ThreadedServer* class:

```py
def __del__(self):
    #print("Closing server socket:", self.sock)
    self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.sock.close()
```

This is not really necessary, since the server will be destroyed at program end, and all the resources will be freed at that point anyway.

#### 2. Close each client socket

Either:

- Add a *finally* clause ([[Python.Docs]: Compound statements - The try statement](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)) to the *try* in *listenToClient* (while we are at this point, you could also rename the method to something like *listen_to_client*):

  ```py
  # ...
  try:
      # Socket operation that might raise exceptions (con.recv)
  except:
      return False
  finally:
      #print("Closing connection:", con)
      con.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
      con.close()
  ```
- Extend the *Thread* class, and use that in *ThreadedServer.listen* (this is more elegant):

  ```py
  class ConnectionHandlingThread(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, target, connection, address):
          self.connection = connection
          super().__init__(target=target, args=(connection, address))

      def run(self):
          super().run()
          #print("Closing connection:", self.connection)
          self.connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
          self.connection.close()
  ```

  and its usage:

  ```py
  ConnectionHandlingThread(listen_to_client, con, address).start()
  ```

#### Alternative

All this looks a bit like reinventing the wheel. The boilerplate for this exact scenario is already present in the *socketserver* module (part of *Python* standard library). For more details, check [[Python.Docs]: socketserver - Asynchronous Mixins](https://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins).