# Python function to check if still alive

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, python-server-pages

I am running 2 python scripts: one server script and one client(both Windows 10),who connects to the server.

If for example the connection is lost because the client system restarts and the python script does have autorun by startup, how can I reconnect? Because when I do not restart the server it has an error when the client restarted.

Is there a function or trick someone knows to check if the clients script is still running(so I can remotely restart the server)? Or even beter something that doesn't let the server have a connection error if the client system restarts.

*shown: simple python chatroom*

**SERVER**

```
import time, socket, sys
 
new_socket = socket.socket()
host_name = socket.gethostname()
s_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
 
port = 8080
 
new_socket.bind((host_name, port))
print( "Binding successful!”)
print("This is your IP: ", s_ip)
 
name = input('Enter name: ')
 
new_socket.listen(1) 
 
 
conn, add = new_socket.accept()
 
print("Received connection from ", add[0])
print('Connection Established. Connected From: ',add[0])
 
client = (conn.recv(1024)).decode()
print(client + ' has connected.')
 
conn.send(name.encode())
while True:
    message = input('Me : ')
    conn.send(message.encode())
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(client, ':', message)
```

**CLIENT**

```
import time, socket, sys
 
socket_server = socket.socket()
server_host = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(server_host)
sport = 8080
 
print('This is your IP address: ',ip)
server_host = input('Enter friend\'s IP address:')
name = input('Enter Friend\'s name: ')
 
 
socket_server.connect((server_host, sport))
 
socket_server.send(name.encode())
server_name = socket_server.recv(1024)
server_name = server_name.decode()
 
print(server_name,' has joined...')
while True:
    message = (socket_server.recv(1024)).decode()
    print(server_name, ":", message)
    message = input("Me : ")
    socket_server.send(message.encode())
```

Comment: If you need a constant connection, implement a heartbeat system, in which the client periodically sends some sort of message to the server, and if it doesn't respond in time, consider the connection lost and re-establish one.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail about how you've implemented the server and client - along with some actual code. There are many ways of writing server and client software and without knowing how you've done it it is very hard to help you.

Comment: @Raniz, thank you for your feedback! I updated my post and now it has the source code.

Comment: @AKX that would be hard since the send and receive commands are blocking. Or you can make Threads but I am not sure if that is the solution.

Comment: @Augurkenplukker12 You'll need to set up suitable socket timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a multithread server. In a multithread server, a new independent thread (separated from the main thread) is created for each client.

So, when your client stops, the server finishes only the client's thread, while the main thread keeps running, waiting for new clients.

There are plenty of examples of multithread servers in web. Here are a few examples:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-multi-threading-python/
- [How to make a simple multithreaded socket server in Python that remembers clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828264/how-to-make-a-simple-multithreaded-socket-server-in-python-that-remembers-client)
- https://www.positronx.io/create-socket-server-with-multiple-clients-in-python/