# Python recv() doesn't wait for client response

Tags: python, php, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to set up a communication via socket between a PHP page (client) and a Python script (server). The PHP page has a button that, when clicked, sends "next" to the server. This part works but the problem happens when I refresh the page. In this situation I'm not writing anything to the server, yet, the function `recv()` of my server seems to receive something (an empty string) because the next lines are executed. Can someone tell me what's going on ?

`client.php`

```
<?php

$host    = '127.0.0.1';
$port    = 5353;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Could not create socket\n');
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die('Could not connect to server\n');

if(isset($_POST['btnNext'])) {
    $msg_to_server = 'next';
    socket_write($socket, $msg_to_server, strlen($msg_to_server)) or die('Could not send data to server\n');
    $msg_from_server = socket_read($socket, 1024) or die('Could not read server response\n');
    echo 'Server said : ' . $msg_from_server;
}

?>

<form action='' method='POST' >
    <button name='btnNext' type='submit'>Next</button>
</form>
```

`server.py`

```
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5353

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen(5)

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    # doesn't wait for the client response :
    msg_from_client = client_socket.recv(5000).decode()
    print('Client said : ' + msg_from_client)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your php part to this.

```
<?php

$host    = '127.0.0.1';
$port    = 5357;

if(isset($_POST['btnNext'])) {

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Could not create socket\n');
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die('Could not connect to server\n');
//creating socket connection under condition o.w making those empty str
$msg_to_server = 'next';
socket_write($socket, $msg_to_server, strlen($msg_to_server)) or die('Could not send data to server\n');
$msg_from_server = socket_read($socket, 1024) or die('Could not read server response\n');
echo 'Server said : ' . $msg_from_server;
   socket_close($socket); //probably ?
}

?>
```

Comment: This works but it is still weird behavior. It seems that either the recv() function doesn't wait for a reponse, or socket_connect() acts like socket_write() and sends an empty string . Thank you.

Comment: well i guess you  are trying with many requests. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828264/how-to-make-a-simple-multithreaded-socket-server-in-python-that-remembers-client